# Некорректное сохранение данных на Python

Tags: python

Есть Telegram bot который сохраняет id пользователей в .txt файл. Также с помощью команды, бот удаляет id из .txt.

Проблема: После удаления пустые строки не заполняются. Новые id добавляются вниз.
[image: Пример.]

Функция добавления и удаления из txt:
[image: cкрин]

Comment: Очевидно, что проблема в функции, которая производит удаление. Но не видя её кода ничего более подробного сказать нельзя.

Comment: код текстом, а не картинкой принято оставлять

Comment: вы добавляете ид юзера и `\n`, а удаляете только сам ид, но оставляете `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Замените на `.replace(idd + '\n', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо заменить `cle = open( "idBL.txt", "r").read().replace( idd, "")` на `cle = open( "idBL.txt", "r").read().replace(idd + "\n" , "")` , т.к. вы добавляете idd и \n, а удаляете только idd, потому \n остаётся и данные записываются через строчку